# How can i add facebook like box on a flash site

Tags: flash, facebook, fbml

```
<item>
    <!-- About Us Item Title -->
    <title><![CDATA[<font color="#FFFFFF">Facebook Updates</font>]]></title>
    <!-- SUB TITLE -->
    <!-- <subTitle><![CDATA[<font color="#FFBC53">Click To View Facebook Updates</font>]]></subTitle> -->
    <subTitle><![CDATA[<font color="#FFBC53" size="+10">Coming Soon...</font>]]></subTitle>
    <!-- Path To Midsection Image -->   
    <image>midsection/images/tour.jpg</image>
    <!-- About Us Description Text HTML Formatted -->
    <description><![CDATA[<font color="#FFFFFF">  </font> ]]></description> 
</item>
```

Can some one help me, how can i add facebook like box on a flash site...

Above is a block in a flash site i want to show up fb like box.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for the Like Box is here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/
You could include it in a standard html div, but embedding it inside a flash movie isn't possible

Answer (score 0):

The only way is create a dialog and put the code of the like box in it.
Then you press a button in Flash. This button make a call to the PHP. The PHP open the dialog with the like box and then return something to Flash.